# How can I display pictures saved in a database?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

This is my models file. I tried checking if there's a method for displaying class objects as a non-string.... Is there anything like that?

```
class Images(models.Model):
    # height = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # width=models.PositiveIntegerField()

    file=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    #height_field='height', width_field = 'width
    # file = models.ImageField(#upload_to=user_directory_path,
    # width_field=100, height_field=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Give a short description of the image", max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This the html file

```
h1>This is the House Page</h1>

{%for pic in pic%}
{{pic}}
{% comment %} <img src="{{pic}}" alt=""> {% endcomment %}
{%endfor%}
```

This is the view for the above html page

```
def House(request):
    pic = Images.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'house.html', {'pic': pic})
```

This is the form that saves the picture

```
<h1>Upload Your Image Here</h1>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!--To allow images-->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And this is the view for the above html page

```
def imgUpload(request):
    form = ImageForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.POST['file']
        name = request.POST['name']
        description = request.POST['description']
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        pic = Images.objects.create(file=file, name=name, description=description)
        pic.save()
        return render(request, 'house.html', {'pic': pic})
            #return HttpResponseRedirect('/fileupload.html?submitted=True')

    else:
        return render(request, 'fileupload.html',{'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your model property get_img_url:

```
class Images(models.Model):
    # height = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # width=models.PositiveIntegerField()

    file=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    #height_field='height', width_field = 'width
    # file = models.ImageField(#upload_to=user_directory_path,
    # width_field=100, height_field=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Give a short description of the image", max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def get_img_url(self):
        if self.file and hasattr(self.file, 'url'):
            return self.file.url
        else:
            return ''
```

then in template:

```
h1>This is the House Page</h1>

{%for pic in pic%}
{{pic}}
{% comment %} <img src="{{pic.get_img_url}}" alt=""> {% endcomment %}
{%endfor%}
```